# Remove unused global object from static library while linking

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker-flags

We have a static library which contains some global class objects. This static library is used by a shared library which contains some wrapper classes. The code in shared library does not refer the global objects and also does not call the functions which use these global objects. But when I was going through the disassembly of the shared library, I noticed that the unreferenced global objects were still included in the library.

To explain the problem, I have provided a dummy code below:

```
// A.h
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>

class IBase
{
public:
    IBase(int value) : m_value(value) {}
    virtual ~IBase() {}
    virtual int Get() const = 0;
    virtual void Print() const = 0;

    const int m_value;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public IBase
{
public:
    Derived() : IBase(10) {}
    int Get() const override { return m_value; }
    void Print() const override { printf("%s\n", typeid(T).name()); }

    static void DoSomething();
};

template<typename T>
Derived<T> derived;
```

```
// B.h
#pragma once

void Foo();
void Bar();
```

```
// B.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void Foo()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    derived<int>.Print();
}

void Bar()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

I compile above code into a static library using following two commands:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I . -fPIC -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Os -c B.cpp -o B.o
ar rcs libstatic.a B.o
```

Then I have the following code in shared library:

```
// test.h
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void func();
```

```
// test.cpp
#include "test.h"

void func()
{
    Bar();
}
```

I compile shared library using following command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -shared -fPIC -I . -L . -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -flto -Os -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL -fvisibility=hidden -o libshared.so test.cpp -l:libstatic.a
```

I see following lines in disassembly taken using `objdump -Cd libshared.so`.

```
0000000000000810 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_B.cpp>:
 810:   48 8d 05 31 08 20 00    lea    0x200831(%rip),%rax        # 201048 <guard variable for derived<int>>
 817:   80 38 00                cmpb   $0x0,(%rax)
 ...
0000000000000930 <Derived<int>::~Derived()>:
 ...
0000000000000932 <Derived<int>::Get() const>:
 ...
0000000000000936 <Derived<int>::~Derived()>:
 ...
0000000000000940 <Derived<int>::Print() const>:
 940:   48 8b 05 b1 06 20 00    mov    0x2006b1(%rip),%rax        # 200ff8 <typeinfo for int@CXXABI_1.3>
 947:   48 8b 50 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rdx
 ...
```

I think I am using the correct linker garbage collection and link time optimization flags. Since `Foo` isn't called from the shared library, so I don't see it in disassembly. `Foo` is the only function using the global object. Then why is the global object still not removed from the library? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is, the presence of `Foo` in the translation unit caused the compiler to instantiate `derived<int>`. The linker is unable to discard it because, for all it knows, the object's constructor may have observable side effects.

Comment: Yes. If I remove Foo() from B.h and B.cpp, then I don't see the global object related stuff in the final shared library.

Comment: I suspect that, if you simply split `Foo` and `Bar` into two separate source files, the linker would be able to pick one without the other.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I split them into two different files and it is working. So, I have one possible solution now. Thanks! :) But is there any other way which does not involve splitting the functions into two separate files?

Comment: @jyotesh Can you recompile static library with `-fvisibility=hidden`?

Comment: @yugr I tried recompiling static library with this command - `g++ -std=c++17 -I . -fPIC -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -Os -c B.cpp -o B.o`. The final shared library still had the code for `Derived`.